# Making RadionButtons appear infront of a GroupBox

Tags: vb.net, forms, debugging, radio-button, groupbox

When I dynamically create a `GroupBox` and add 4 `RadionButton`s inside the `GroupBox` it somehow puts the `RadionButton`s behind the `GroupBox`.

I have the code for the `GroupBox` first therefore why do the `RadionButton`s not show over the `GroupBox`?

Code for reference:

```
multichoicegroupbox(Qnum) = New GroupBox : multichoicegroupbox(Qnum).Location = New Point(X, (Y - 5))
multichoicegroupbox(Qnum).Width = 230 : multichoicegroupbox(Qnum).Height = 120
frmQuizForStudents.Controls.Add(multichoicegroupbox(Qnum))

For MultichoiceCheckNum = 1 to 4
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum) = New RadioButton
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum).Location = New Point(multichoicegroupbox(Qnum).Location.X + 10,
                                                            (multichoicegroupbox(Qnum).Location.Y + (MultichoiceCheckNum * 24)))
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum).Font = New Font("Arial", 9)
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum).Text = multichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum)
    multichoicegroupbox(Qnum).Controls.Add(rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum))

    Y += 24
Next MultichoiceCheckNum
```

When I comment out the `New Point` line of code for the `GroupBox`, the `GroupBox` appears in the top left of the screen with all 4 `RadionButton`s working on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Location of the RadioButton is relative to their container. Instead you specify a Location relative to the Form. The buttons are there but are out of sight.

In other words you shouldn't add the location of the GroupBox in your calculation but just consider the top/left position of the GroupBox as the position 0,0 of the coordinates for your RadioButtons.

```
For MultichoiceCheckNum = 1 to 4
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum) = New RadioButton
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum).Location = New Point(10,
                                           10 + (MultichoiceCheckNum * 24))
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum).Font = New Font("Arial", 9)
    rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum).Text = multichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum)
    multichoicegroupbox(Qnum).Controls.Add(rdbmultichoice(MultichoiceCheckNum))

Next MultichoiceCheckNum
```